# Can't retrieve embedded object from a MongoDB document - MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using the MERN stack for my current project. So I am facing this problem:

Let's say that I have the following document in MongoDB :

```
{
   name: "Tesla Inc.",
   category: "Automotive",
   contact: {
     state : {
       name: "Texas",
       city: "Austin", 
         address: {
          streetName: "Tesla Road",
          number: '1'
        } 
     }
  }
}
```

What I get as response after using `findOne({ name : "Tesla"})` is :

```
 {_id: '637e4397f6723844191aa03d', name: 'Tesla', category: 
 'Automotive', contact: {…}}
```

As you can see contact object is `undefined`

**Follows my coding process**

1. This is my Express route for quering the database :

```
storeRoutes.route("/enterprise").get(function (req, res) {
  let db_connect = dbo.getDb("res");

  const query = { name : "Tesla"};
  
  db_connect
  .collection("stores")
  .findOne(query,function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(result);
  });
});
```

**Result**: After typing browser url `http://localhost:5000/enterprise` returns the expected value:

```
{"_id":"637e4397f6723844191aa03d","name":"Tesla","category":"Automotive","contact":{"state":{"name":"Texas","city":"Austin","address":{"streetName":"Tesla Road","number":"1"}}}}
```

2. This a Retriever Data Function that returns the data object:

```
  function GetEnterprise() {
    const [store, setStore] = useState({
      })
    useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchData() {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/enterprise`);
    
        if (!response.ok) {
          const message = `An error has occurred: ${response.statusText}`;
          window.alert(message);
          return;
        }
        const record = await response.json();
        if (!record) {
        //  window.alert(`Record with id ${id} not found`);
          window.alert(`Record with id  not found`);
          return;
        }     
        setStore(record);
      }      
      fetchData();      
      return;
    }, [1]); 
    
    //debugging
    console.log('tesla: ' + store);
    window.store = store;
    let res_json = JSON.stringify(store);
    console.log('res_json :' + res_json);
    
    return store;
  }
```

**Result**:
Before GetEnterprise() function returns `store` I have added these 4 lines of code for debugging:

```
 console.log('tesla: ' + store);
 window.store = store;
 let res_json = JSON.stringify(store);
 console.log('res_json :' + res_json);
```

1st line logs `[object Object]` which is not that informative for what I am getting back as a response.
So I came up with 2nd line which enables to debug directly from the browser console.
After I type store my console logs:

```
{_id: '637e4397f6723844191aa03d', name: 'Tesla', category: 'Automotive', contact: {…}}
```

So my `contact` object is missing(`undefined`).

Now fun fact is the 3rd and 4rd lines :

```
  let res_json = JSON.stringify(store);
  console.log('res_json :' + res_json);
```

My console logs the whole object as expected:

```
 {"_id":"637e4397f6723844191aa03d","name":"Tesla","category":"Automotive","contact":{"state":{"name":"Texas","city":"Austin","address":{"streetName":"Tesla Road","number":"1"}}}}
```

Which is really weird.
I guess it has something to do with the async and await functions. But I am not sure.
What am I doing wrong?
Any suggestions ..?

Comment: It should be `response.contact.state.address.streetName` without the `.city` portion

Comment: @NickParsons thank you for the reply. I've just edited the description in a better manner. So your comment got irrelevant now. But it was not that case either.